# How to work with 8-bit char data in HLSL?

Tags: hlsl, directcompute

I'm converting some OpenCL code to DirectCompute and need to process 8-bit character strings in a compute shader but don't find an HLSL data type for "byte" or "char". OpenCL supports a "char" type, so I was expecting an equivalent. What is the best way to define and access the data?

It seems that the data can be passed by treating it as a series of "uint" types and unpacking it with bit-shifting, AND-ing, etc. but this seems like it will cause unnecessary overhead. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found two ways to do this, although they both require working with int/uint values in the HLSL since I haven't found an 8-bit data type:

Option 1 is to let the "view" handle the translation:

- Pass the original data as a byte/char buffer.
- Set the Shader Resource View format (D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC.Format) to DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UINT
- Define the HLSL data type as `Buffer<uint>`
- Reference each byte using its byte offset (i.e., treat it as a buffer of bytes not a buffer of uints). Each character is
  automatically promoted to a uint value.

Option 2 is to treat each 4-byte sequence as a uint, using the format DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, and manually extract each character using something like this:

```
Buffer<uint> buffer;
uint offset = ...;    
uint ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4;
ch1 =  buffer[offset] >> 24;
ch2 = (buffer[offset] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
ch3 = (buffer[offset] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
ch4 = (buffer[offset] & 0x000000ff);
```

Either way you end up working with 32-bit values but at least they correspond to individual characters.

Comment: This seems right to me.  There are also ByteAddressBuffers but they have the same uint32 granularity restriction.
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/DirectCompute/doc/DirectCompute_Programming_Guide.pdf

Comment: it works but except for structured buffer. which only supports 2, 4 bytes access.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ByteAddressBuffer, create ByteAddressBuffer with stride of one, set the srv format to DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UINT.

In Hlsl, you use "Load" function to load uint32 data, mask data with 0xFF000000 to get first 8bit, finally bit shift to correct bit address.

I work in unreal engine, and these are my code:

```
c++

create ByteAddressBuffer:
            MaskBufferRHI = RHICreateBuffer(DataLength * sizeof(uint8), BUF_Static | BUF_ByteAddressBuffer | BUF_ShaderResource, sizeof(uint8), ERHIAccess::SRVCompute, MaskCreateInfo); // MaskCreateInfo contain all the data I need.
create svr with uint8:
            RHICreateShaderResourceView(MaskBufferRHI, sizeof(uint8), PF_R8_UINT);


hlsl
define buffer:
            ByteAddressBuffer InMaskBuffer;
retrieve uint8 data to uint32:
            const uint InMask = (InMaskBuffer.Load(SomeID) & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

(load function fill uint32 InMask with 4 uint8 data in out buffer at once, we need to mask out those data.)
```